# Sliding background in Libgdx

Tags: android, libgdx, 2d-games

I´m new with libgx and i have a basic question. I want an background like an image that repeats indefinetely, and moves down. I did with 2 images and it worked, but the problem is that is very slow. I stored the images with 512x512px.
My code is very simple but i dont know what im doing wrong.

```
public void render() {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0.2f, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    offset -= 600 * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
        offset = offset % 512;
    camera.update();
    batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
    batch.begin();
    batch.draw(backgroundImage, 0, offset);
    batch.draw(backgroundImage, 0, offset + 512);
    batch.draw(bucketImage, 0, offset + 1024);
    batch.end();
}
```

Any suggestions will be appreciated 
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Have you checked to see in you can accomplish what you want do with Tiles (https://code.google.com/p/libgdx-users/wiki/Tiles)

Comment: Does this help you? http://www.badlogicgames.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=17&t=1795

Comment: `camera.update()` and `batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined)` don't need to be called unless the camera position or zoom was modified. Removing them may or may not have a significant effect on performance.

Comment: In fact i dont need tiles, because i have 1 image only, the problem is that its slow to render. I see the paralax background but its not what im looking for. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any reason your render method would cause a slowdown, are you sure the slowdown is happening there? I would bet it's not. Narrow down the root cause of the slowdown which is probably somewhere else in your code.

(I didn't have enough reputation to comment)

Comment: Yes, I think that the error is there because I created a new project only with this code and worked slow too. Maybe it´s a configuration problem, but I could not detect it. Thanks for the answer!